# How to change many XCP signals at once in the ECU using XCP protocol and CAPL?

Tags: capl, xcp

I'm actually working with CANoe and CAPL language on the test of some XCP signals in an ECU, thus I need to change those XCP signals all at the same time (as mentionned in the customer specifications) in order to check the behaviour of the software implemented in the ECU with this change, but all I know is to change one signal at a time, how can I implement with CAPL the update of many XCP signals at the same time?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SO. If you haven't already, please have a look at these two guides: [how to ask a well received question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what shoud I do when someone answers my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism you're looking for is called page switching. Unfortunately, it has to be configured and enabled in your ECU first.

If it is, then you can use CAPL functions `xcpGetCalPage` to see what page are you on and `xcpSetCalPage` to change the page.

Comment: Can it be done if the physical ECU is not available and the code is running on a VN8910A for instance?